# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/Codec

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit, lucene

I have a project needing Lucene(**4.3.0**) and add the following dependenies:
lucene-core,lucene-analyzers-common,lucene-queries,lucene-queryparser.

And,after add lucene-codecs dependency,also get the same error.

but, the lucene-core jar contains the **Codec** `class`

----- begin exception -----

```
I/TestRunner(2443): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/Codec
I/TestRunner(2443):     at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:118)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:144)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at com.my.search.SearchIndexManager.newWriter(SearchIndexManager.java:301)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at com.my.search.SearchIndexManager.addIndexState(SearchIndexManager.java:95)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at com.my.SearchOperation.addIndexer(SearchOperation.java:68)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at com.my.test.SearchOperationTest.testSearchWithFilter(SearchOperationTest.java:208)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
I/TestRunner(2443):     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
I/TestRunner(2736): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'Lucene42' does not exist. You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.The current classpath supports the following names: []
I/TestRunner(2736):     at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.lookup(NamedSPILoader.java:109)
I/TestRunner(2736):     at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.forName(Codec.java:95)
I/TestRunner(2736):     at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:122)
I/TestRunner(2736):     ... 19 more
```

----- end exception -----

Comment: have marked your dependencies as exported in Eclipse?

Comment: this is a maven project and coded in elcipse.all is ok in compile.
but error when run test code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling turns up some interesting results.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4204

According to the issue above, the Android APK builder removes some files in the META-INF/services directory, which is required by Lucene. They suggest some workarounds, like adding the necessary files from the lucene jars directly to the APK via some ant tasks done after the APK builder is done. Just be careful, since some lucene jars use the same files in the META-INF/services directory, and you may overwrite them uneccessarily.

I would actually suggest that you use the android maven plugin, as they have applied a fix for this already (see https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=97). Just use the latest version of the plugin (or any version above 3.2.1).

Comment: I run Lucene4x in android successful using maven-android-plugin.
how to run test code in eclipse using "right click test code class -> run as -> Android Junit Test"?

Comment: Hi CHmoonKa. I'm afraid I am not that familiar with building Android apps in Eclipse. What build system do they use? To they have an Ant build file (build.xml)? If they are using Ant, then it may be possible to add some sort of post-compile target into the build file that copies the necessary files from the Lucene jar onto the APK.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your problem is not that `Codec` class is not found but that another class  (which is an SPI provider) is not found (see `Caused by`). If you see in [Lucene package description](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/package-summary.html#package_description) at the very bottom (also see [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/Codec.html)) this class is declared as an SPI provider in the `META-INF` folder of one of your jars.

So search your jars to find a `META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec` file, open it and see the name of the class. You are missing the jar that contains that class

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you very much. I am busy for some time.I can find the META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec in lucene-core.jar,but it do not exist under META-INF directory in android apk file.

Comment: @CHmoonKa The file just needs to exist inside a jar that is in your classpath. It seems that the implementation class is inside the `lucene-core` but it doesn't have a chance to be loaded. Probably the Android test runner messes up with your classpath (see the message: *current classpath supports the following names: []*). Can you add the whole code for the test you are trying to run?